# Multi-index all-pairs comparison of groups in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bioinformatics

**Question (Formally)**

I have a flat table *df* with columns *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *e* where *a* and *b* are one-to-many, as are (*b* and *c*) and (*c* and *d*).  *d* is a unique index, and *e* is an arbitrary integer.

Let *grouped = df.groupby(by=['a','b','c'])*.  Each group will then essentially consist of its label and a set of key-value pairs *{d*:*e}*.  I want to keep all rows in some group *x* if there is no other group *y* in *grouped* such that

- *x.a == y.a*
- *x.b != y.b*
- for any value *p* in *x.e*, and any value *u* in *y.e* , *abs(p - u) < 100*

If any group *y* meets these conditions, then no rows from *x* or *y* should be in the final result.

---

**Same question, applied**

I am using this in the context of bioinformatics.  Specifically, *(a,b,c,d,e) = (chromosome, strand, gene_id, transcript_id, transcription_start_site)*.  Every gene is on exactly one strand ('+' or '-', corresponding to the two strands of the DNA double helix) of exactly one chromosome, and every gene has at least one transcript.  Each transcript has a transcription start site (TSS), which is the integer position of the transcript on its chromosome measured in nucleotide base pairs (bp).  Two transcripts of the same gene may or many not share a TSS.

In biological terms, I want to find genes that do not have bi-direction promoters.  This means I want to find all genes that have no transcripts with start sites within some *n* of any transcription start site of a gene on the *opposite* strand.  As a side-note, for ease of example I chose *n=100*, but a more biologically accurate *n* would likely be in the range of 150 to 1000.

---

**Example data**

```
a = chromosome    b = strand    c = gene_id    d = transcript_id    e = tss
  chr1              +             ENSG001        ENST001             11865
  chr1              +             ENSG001        ENST002             11868
  chr1              +             ENSG001        ENST003             12006
  chr1              -             ENSG002        ENST004             29370
  chr1              -             ENSG002        ENST005             24886
  chr1              +             ENSG003        ENST006             29550
```

If this was the complete list of data and *n=100*, all rows would be included in the answer.  However, if *n=1000*, only the first three rows where gene_id=ENSG001 should be included.

---

**Considerations**

The table is huge, so doing a giant cartesian, paring it to down, etc. isn't feasible (and also would be ugly).  Which pandas/numpy methods could I use to select rows fitting my criteria cleanly and efficiently?  Should I be using something other than groupby, or hierarchal indexing or something?  I'm not particularly familiar with pandas syntax, so explicit examples would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a small sample of your data and an example of the desired output for us to better visualize and work with.

Comment: Hi aus_lacy -  I've added the specific context of my question and some example data.  Please let me know if there is anything else I might add.